# Suggest me a wordpress plugin for upcoming events with date highlight plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

[image: refernce imaage]

suggest me a good wordpress theme that is similar to image. Even its a horizontal scroll that wont be a problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events calendar is what you would need for this, there are a few other plugins but from what you need events calendar will fit your needs just fine.

Here is the [link](https://theeventscalendar.com/) to the plugin site

And here is the [link](https://wpshindig.com/event-widgets/) to the demo of the event widget

Hope this helps =]

Answer (score 0):

I would go for **WP Event Solution** (Eventin) - https://themewinter.com/eventin/
I didnt liked The events calendar graphically at all, and there are a lot of things hidden behind paywalls. Scroll on that page a bit down to see comparison with other plugins. (It has shortcodes generator for calendar with events which can you put to pages)